# Orthogonal matrices with rational coefficients generating free subgroup

Tags: group-theory, orthogonal-matrices, free-groups

I wonder, is it possible for two matrices in $\mathrm{SO}(n), \ n>2$ with rational entries to generate a free subgroup of $\mathrm{SO}(n)$? If yes, is it possible to construct two such matrices ? For irrational coefficients there is no problem of course.

Comment: This is done for $n = 3$ here: https://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2007/09/17/that-trick-where-you-embed-the-free-group-into-a-lie-group/

Comment: In general, consider reading about the [Tits Alternative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tits_alternative#:~:text=The%20Tits%20alternative%20is%20an,dealt%20with%20by%20elementary%20means)..

Comment: @QiaochuYuan this is great, thank you. Please consider to post it as an answer, so I can accept it. Regarding the Banach-Tarski paradox, so far I've only seen orthogonal matrices with irrational coefficients in the proof, as at the end of the link you posted.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Am I understanding correctly that the Tits alternative states that there are a lot of free subgroups in linear groups, but gives no way to explicitly construct them?

Comment: It actually gives a way to construct them as well, once you have a pair of noncommuting orthogonal matrices $A, B$ of infinite order, you will raise them to a suitable power, then $<A^k, B^k>$ will be free.

Comment: @MoisheKohan thank you for the details. Do you have any reference for this construction ? Can't find it stated explicitly in the Tits original paper, but perhaps I overlooked it.

Comment: What I wrote is for subgroups of $SO(3)$ (which suffices for the answer to your question). I am not sure about a reference, but one sees this by following Tits' general argument. I can write a sketch of a proof if you like. The general case is more involved and (asaik) one needs more assumptions on the generating set $A, B$ (but constructing such matrices in a given subgroup of $SO(n)$ can still be made explicit, it is explained in great detail in papers by Breuillard and Gelander).

Comment: @MoisheKohan thanks again. Its ok, I see that Breuillard and Gelander have a series of papers on similar topics, I will read them.